# how can "2016-12-31T00-00-00"^^dateTime is not correct in owl

Tags: datetime, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is my constrain

```
(canBeRecommendedFrom value "2016-01-01T00-00-00"^^dateTime) and (canBeRecommendedUntil value "2016-12-31T00-00-00"^^dateTime)
```

I am receiving error saying that`"2016-12-31T00-00-00"^^dateTime` is not correct, as the following:

> LogRecord{ERROR, 1457538506675, An error occurred during reasoning: Literal "2016-12-31T00-00-00"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime is malformed., Classification Thread}

#### update

it sounds like there are exceptions for both of the dates

Comment: Did you mean 2016-01-01T00:00:00

Comment: @MrLister it sounds like both of them is not correct, though i have used the same format in different ontology it was working, i don't know why this one is not working

Comment: @MrLister oh i see, thank you, yes it is the dots, thank you, you may write an answer please ?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `xsd` prefix:

```
(canBeRecommendedFrom value "2016-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime) and (canBeRecommendedUntil value "2016-12-31T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime)
```

Comment: In my answer I corrected both the missing dots and the xsd prefix that eas missing

Comment: but still not correct to put the `xsd` part, in my protege it's working without `xsd` and if i put `xsd`, it is wrong